# I am trying to use If() condition , however, it's not working in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have few field in my store method, so I wanted to use if() condition, but it's not working

here is code

```
    if($request->has('link'))
    {
        $data['link']=$request->link;

    }
    if($request->has('content'))
    {
        $data['content']=$request->content;

    }
```

Comment: _but it's not working_ What does that mean exactly?

Comment: Could you provide some context? What do you mean with "it's not working"? In which file are you? Do you even have the "<?php" tags at the very beginning of the file? Do you have PHP installed and running? Without context, nobody can help you :)

Comment: try with replace `$request->has('content')` to `$request->get('content')`.

Comment: here is code https://pastebin.com/SsV6Fdnp

Comment: if (request('file')) {
            $file = request('file');
            $file_name = time() . $file->getClientOriginalName();
            $file->move('uploads/posts', $file_name);
            $data['file'] = 'uploads/posts/'.$file_name;
        }
        // Create the Post with the $data Array

       $post = Post::create($data);
        //$post=Post::whereBetween('created_at',[$date_time, $to])->get();
        Session::flash('success', 'New Blog has been Published on Website for Particular Menu');
        return redirect()->back();

Comment: have you tried `if(isset($request->link))` ?

Comment: @danish-khan-I, I tried, it's still same issue

Comment: then you are not getting the data.. try `dd($request)` and check if you are getting data or not.

Comment: @danish-khan-I, yes, getting the data, i tried with dd($request)

Comment: can you post it there...

Comment: array:6 [▼
  "_token" => "eUe1FQ44CIxElhCjkDcoXVdJk9wcRaHckS2bcDXw"
  "category_id" => "5"
  "date_time" => "sd"
  "title" => "sd"
  "link" => "sd"
  "content" => null
]

Comment: https://pastebin.com/SsV6Fdnp here is code

Answer (score 0):

use `$request->filled('link')` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can you below codes....

```
if($request->link == NULL)
             or
if(empty($request->link))
             or
if ($this->isEmptyString($value)) return false;
```

These are some alternative you can use.